Podemos usar o presente do subjuntivo com a conjunção "se"?
Acho que ninguém estranha as seguintes frases:

"Se formos a pé, perderemos o filme".


"Se fôssemos a pé, perderíamos o filme".

Que usam o futuro e o passado do subjuntivo. Agora a frase:

"Se sejamos fracos, não consigamos vencer"

Fica estranha. O presente do subjuntivo não pode nunca ser usado nas construções com o "se"? No latim, eu acho que pode.

O significado das duas primeiras construções é claro, o que a construção com "se" denotaria? O que denota em latim?

@stafusa eu não sou muito proficiente em latim, mas acho que se traduziria como passado do subjuntivo pro Português. A oração com "se" é subordinada e segue a consecutio temporum.

Desculpa mas você sabe latim mas não sabia distinguir os tempos em português? Me parece um pouco estranho isso.

A pergunta claramente não é sobre distinguir os tempos, é sobre por quê a conjunção 'se' não aceita o presente do subjuntivo.

Sim, a conjunção se usa seguido do presente em orações condicionais.
Se somos fracos, não conseguimos vencer.
Se falo com você, é porque somos amigas.

Se chama condicional factuais ou reais (do simples, não composto).


– Condicionais factuais, ou reais:
Se acontece x, também acontece y. Neste caso, usam-se os tempos do modo
indicativo. Na oração introduzida pela conjunção se (subordinada)
usa-se o presente; na outra (subordinante) usa-se o presente, o
futuro, ou o modo imperativo:
Ex.: a) «Se vens cedo, jantas comigo»
(presente + presente)
in Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa, ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/… [consultado em 15-06-2024]

"Se sejamos fracos, não consigamos vencer" não funciona. O primeiro verbo precisa estar no presente na oração subordinada, e o segundo verbo na oração principal tambem. E no caso dado abaixo o subjuntivo (no caso, pretérito imperfeito do subjuntivo) sempre iria na oração encabeçada por se ou seja a subordinada, nunca na principal. Pode-se usar: se somos fracos, se formos fracos ou se fôssemos fracos para as formas simples do condicional.
Essas são as outras formas do condicional simples (isto é,não composto)

Se formos fracos, não conseguiremos vencer".
futuro do subjuntivo + futuro

Se fôssemos fracos, não conseguiríamos vencer."
pretérito imperfeito do subjuntivo + futuro do pretérito



A pergunta não é sobre presente-indicativo + presente-indicativo, é sobre presente-subjuntivo + presente-indicativo. O porquê da segunda opção ser incorrecta não foi dado nem respaldado por uma fonte.

A terceira frase é tradicionalmente considerada incorrecta. A conjunção 'se' é regida pelo futuro e passado do subjuntivo/conjuntivo, e 'caso' pelo presente e passado.

Enquanto a conjunção 'caso' exige o verbo no presente do subjuntivo, a condicional se reclama pelo futuro do subjuntivo. Haja vista estes exemplos: Caso chova (pres. do subj.), não vá. Caso você fique, é bom avisar. Se eu puder (fut. do subj.), irei a seu gabinete. Se você vier, será bem recebido.

Dicas do Professor Germano – Poder Judiciário de Mato Grosso

Em condicionais hipotéticas, ou seja, na hipótese de x acontecer, y também acontece, a oração com a conjunção 'se' tem o verbo no futuro do subjuntivo, enquanto a oração principal terá o verbo no presente ou no futuro do indicativo.


Há casos em que a oração condicional expressa algo que não aconteceu, ou algo que poderia ter acontecido em um passado ou no plano imaginário.

Escola de Magistrados – TRF da 3ª Região

A conjunção condicional caso não se emprega com o futuro do subjuntivo (ou conjuntivo). Emprega-se com o presente de conjuntivo: "Empresta-me esse livro, caso possas".

Ciberdúvidas

Segundo a esmagadora maioria dos gramáticos, [caso] só vem seguida de verbo no presente do subjuntivo ou no pretérito imperfeito do subjuntivo.

portuguescompestana
Quando o verbo é no passado do conjuntivo/subjuntivo, diferença nenhuma há entre as frases "Se soubessem, teriam dito" e "Caso soubessem, teriam dito", significam exatamente a mesma coisa.
Quando a conjunção correta há de ser empregada, pois em uma frase estará no futuro o verbo e em outra no presente, o sentido é quase o mesmo:
"Se souberem, avisarão" e "Caso saibam, avisarão".

A forma se pode ser[conjunção], [pronome indefinido], [pronome pessoal de dois géneros], [sigla] ou [símbolo].
"se", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2024, https://dicionario.priberam.org/se. Não dizem "preposição"

Naturalmente é conjunção, não preposição. Não sei por quê escrevi um em vez do outro. Corrigido.
